# Get info from Azure Application Inisights through API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to download information from the Azure Application Insights through REST API? I would like to make a simple page that would be a kind of mediator, which asks AI (Application Insights) about the data that was sent by my application.

I found something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx

but I would also have access to the collected bugs.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API is planned, but [Continuous export](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/) is the way to go just at present. You can hose the data into a blob and process it all you like there. Or even better, shift it to a db or dashboard.

We're currently developing the API, so please let us know in MS UserVoice what you'd like: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin